# 20.04. Sound. Sound stopped working on HD 4.40BT bluetooth headset under Headset Head Unit profile

Tags: sound, 20.04, bluetooth, microphone, headset

all! I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop using bluetooth headset.
Internal mic works ok. The other Hi Fi profile works ok, but when i switch the profile to HSP/HFP, there's no sound.

It used to work before the recent update. I've tried to reboot with the previous kernel version, but it did not help.

The device is available in settings.

In pavucontrol all the same. It is present, but there's no sound.

The output from pactl list cards

```
Card #0
    Name: alsa_card.pci-0000_00_1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 7
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "0"
        alsa.card_name = "sof-hda-dsp"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HP-HPSpectrex360Convertible13_ap0xxx--8514"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_soc_skl_hda_dsp"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1f.3-platform-skl_hda_dsp_generic"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/skl_hda_dsp_generic/sound/card0"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "8086"
        device.vendor.name = "Intel Corporation"
        device.product.id = "9dc8"
        device.product.name = "Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "0"
        device.description = "Cannon Point-LP High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    Profiles:
        HiFi: Play HiFi quality Music (sinks: 4, sources: 2, priority: 8000, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: HiFi
    Ports:
        [Out] HDMI3: HDMI3/DP3 Output (priority: 700, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [Out] HDMI2: HDMI2/DP2 Output (priority: 600, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Properties:
                device.product.name = "SAMSUNG"
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [Out] HDMI1: HDMI1/DP1 Output (priority: 500, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [Out] Speaker: Speaker (priority: 100, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [Out] Headphones: Headphones (priority: 200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [In] Mic2: Headphones Stereo Microphone (priority: 200, latency offset: 0 usec, not available)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi
        [In] Mic1: Digital Microphone (priority: 100, latency offset: 0 usec)
            Part of profile(s): HiFi

Card #1
    Name: bluez_card.00_16_94_31_38_AB
    Driver: module-bluez5-device.c
    Owner Module: 26
    Properties:
        device.description = "HD 4.40BT"
        device.string = "00:16:94:31:38:AB"
        device.api = "bluez"
        device.class = "sound"
        device.bus = "bluetooth"
        device.form_factor = "headset"
        bluez.path = "/org/bluez/hci0/dev_00_16_94_31_38_AB"
        bluez.class = "0x240404"
        bluez.alias = "HD 4.40BT"
        device.icon_name = "audio-headset-bluetooth"
        device.intended_roles = "phone"
    Profiles:
        headset_head_unit: Headset Head Unit (HSP/HFP) (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 30, available: yes)
        a2dp_sink: High Fidelity Playback (A2DP Sink) (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 40, available: yes)
        off: Off (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: headset_head_unit
    Ports:
        headset-output: Headset (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit, a2dp_sink
        headset-input: Headset (priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, available)
            Part of profile(s): headset_head_unit
```

How to find the root cause?

The extract from apt history.log

````
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.113'
Install: libllvm10:amd64 (1:10.0.0-4ubuntu1, automatic)
Upgrade: libreoffice-style-breeze:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), evince:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.5-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-math:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), evolution-data-server-common:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), gnome-calendar:amd64 (3.36.1-1, 3.36.2-0ubuntu1), libgphoto2-port12:amd64 (2.5.24-1, 2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1), uno-libs-private:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libvte-2.91-0:amd64 (0.60.1-1ubuntu1, 0.60.3-0ubuntu1~20.04), libedataserverui-1.2-2:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-gtk-3.0:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), gir1.2-mutter-6:amd64 (3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libridl-java:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libevdocument3-4:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.5-0ubuntu1), libuno-salhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), thunderbird-locale-es-ar:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), python3-software-properties:amd64 (0.98.9, 0.98.9.1), thunderbird-locale-es-es:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgphoto2-6:amd64 (2.5.24-1, 2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1), libegl-mesa0:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libreoffice-gtk3:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), shotwell-common:amd64 (0.30.8-0ubuntu2, 0.30.10-0ubuntu0.1), libgtk-3-common:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), libjuh-java:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgtk-3-0:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-core:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libedata-cal-2.0-1:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libglapi-mesa:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libasound2-data:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu1), snapd:amd64 (2.44.3+20.04, 2.45.1+20.04), libreoffice-l10n-en-gb:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-l10n-en-za:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgphoto2-l10n:amd64 (2.5.24-1, 2.5.25-0ubuntu0.1), libxatracker2:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), gnutls-bin:amd64 (3.6.13-2ubuntu1.1, 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.2), libegl1-mesa:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), evolution-data-server:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), passwd:amd64 (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5, 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04), libreoffice-l10n-de:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-l10n-es:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-l10n-ru:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.36.1.1-1ubuntu1, 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04), libmutter-6-0:amd64 (3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), software-properties-gtk:amd64 (0.98.9, 0.98.9.1), python3-uno:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libuno-cppuhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgbm1:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), mutter-common:amd64 (3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), thunderbird-gnome-support:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), deja-dup:amd64 (40.6-1ubuntu2, 40.7-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-base-core:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-ogltrans:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libebackend-1.2-10:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libuno-purpenvhelpergcc3-3:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-impress:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), evince-common:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.5-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-style-elementary:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgtk-3-bin:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), libebook-1.2-20:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-help-de:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-help-es:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gir1.2-vte-2.91:amd64 (0.60.1-1ubuntu1, 0.60.3-0ubuntu1~20.04), libreoffice-help-ru:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libevview3-3:amd64 (3.36.0-2, 3.36.5-0ubuntu1), libjurt-java:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-help-common:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), thunderbird-locale-en-gb:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), thunderbird-locale-en-us:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-style-colibre:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), ure:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-writer:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgail-3-0:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-common:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), wpasupplicant:amd64 (2:2.9-1ubuntu4, 2:2.9-1ubuntu4.1), shotwell:amd64 (0.30.8-0ubuntu2, 0.30.10-0ubuntu0.1), login:amd64 (1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5, 1:4.8.1-1ubuntu5.20.04), libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), thunderbird:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libasound2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu1), libuno-cppu3:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), thermald:amd64 (1.9.1-1ubuntu0.1, 1.9.1-1ubuntu0.2), libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libvte-2.91-common:amd64 (0.60.1-1ubuntu1, 0.60.3-0ubuntu1~20.04), fonts-opensymbol:amd64 (2:102.11+LibO6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 2:102.11+LibO6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libebook-contacts-1.2-3:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), gnome-terminal-data:amd64 (3.36.1.1-1ubuntu1, 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04), libgnutls30:amd64 (3.6.13-2ubuntu1.1, 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.2), libedata-book-1.2-26:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-pdfimport:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libecal-2.0-1:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libreoffice-style-tango:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gtk-update-icon-cache:amd64 (3.24.18-1ubuntu1, 3.24.20-0ubuntu1), libuno-sal3:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mesa-vdpau-drivers:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), linux-firmware:amd64 (1.187, 1.187.1), mesa-vulkan-drivers:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libreoffice-help-en-gb:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-help-en-us:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libreoffice-gnome:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libcamel-1.2-62:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libunoloader-java:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libgnutls-dane0:amd64 (3.6.13-2ubuntu1.1, 3.6.13-2ubuntu1.2), libreoffice-calc:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), gnome-terminal:amd64 (3.36.1.1-1ubuntu1, 3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04), thunderbird-locale-de:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), thunderbird-locale-en:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), thunderbird-locale-es:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), thunderbird-locale-ru:amd64 (1:68.8.0+build2-0ubuntu0.20.04.2, 1:68.10.0+build1-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), libedataserver-1.2-24:amd64 (3.36.2-0ubuntu1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu1), libatopology2:amd64 (1.2.2-2.1, 1.2.2-2.1ubuntu1), libreoffice-draw:amd64 (1:6.4.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1, 1:6.4.4-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mutter:amd64 (3.36.2-1ubuntu1~20.04.1, 3.36.3-0ubuntu0.20.04.1), mesa-va-drivers:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), libglx-mesa0:amd64 (20.0.4-2ubuntu1, 20.0.8-0ubuntu1~20.04.1), software-properties-common:amd64 (0.98.9, 0.98.9.1)
End-Date: 2020-07-09  11:07:45```
````